# Python3 Formatar print, para tirar bugs de símbolos

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os

with open('lista.txt', 'r') as lista:
    l = lista.read().splitlines()
    for s in l:
        v = os.system('ping '+s)
        print ((v).format)
```

Esse ping funciona, mas retorna com símbolos asssim: � em letras que tem acento,
vi que o pessoal declara a variável e coloca .format, não tem um jeito mais fácil para não ficar colocando .format em tudo?? e colocar uma vez o unicode utf-8 pro script todo entender??

Desculpe mod;Não consigo de jeito nenhum formatar o código python aqui no stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Ponha esse comando na primeira linha do seu código e deve funcionar para que tudo seja utf-8:

```
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

A IDE pycharm utiliza um outro comando parecido, mas se escrever esse ai ela pedirá para corrigir sem problemas, mas nas outras deve funcionar muito bem.

Uma outra forma de corrigir em lugares específicos é da seguinte maneira:

```
variavel.decode('utf-8')
```

Se não funcionar, informa.

Comment: line 8, in <module>
    print (v.encode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Deu erro, e o primeiro código que você colocou, eu já tinha testado no pycharm, ele não entende. Vou tentar algum modulo que faça isso por enquanto

Comment: Só falta arrumar outro erro agora, a reposta é essa print(ord(v[-1])), mas agora da esse erro:  TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable